# Temporarily switch off all validation on cakePHP form to submit ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using jQuery file upload (blue imp) and using it as an upload field on a form.  On clicking upload validation is triggered on the form (ie - field X is empty and so on).

Alternatives are place the ajax submissions at the end, but that is not intuitive when entering a form - things appear "out of order" to the user.

Not sure how to address this.  Is the upload field then actually a form and I should treat it as such?

Comment: can you paste the code from the controller? Are you performing a `save` on a model?

Comment: which vsalidation you want to stop server side or client side?

Comment: No save on the model, this is client side.  I've just baked the forms and some fields have a required and not empty rule.  After baking the fields have the 'required' tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery file upload (blue imp) is creating a Form with a submit button. If you use it in your view within your own form, it essentially becomes a nested form which is invalid HTML. The browser considers your Upload submit button as the submit button to your original form.
If this is the case, you will have to remove the upload button and put it outside your original form.

If you want to simply remove the required tags and the client validation that comes from the browser, then assuming you are using Cake 2.3+:
Refer to the following section in the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements).

"You can explicitly set required key in options array to override it for a field. To skip browser validation triggering for the whole form you can set option 'formnovalidate' => true for the input button you generate using FormHelper::submit() or set 'novalidate' => true in options for FormHelper::create()"