# CakePHP jQuery async upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create an async file upload but I am hitting a wall.  Here is what I have, in an element:

**Element:**

```
<div style="border:0px solid darkgray; width:100%; text-align: right; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;">
    <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" accept="" id = "templatePath" name = "templatePath" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="104857600">   
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"   id = "bntSubmit" name = "bntSubmit" onclick="submitFileUpload();" >
    </form>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
function submitFileUpload(){
    try{
        var FileUrl = "/staff/passport/upload_file/";
        var request_timeout = 50000;
        var formData = new FormData();
        var files =$( '#templatePath' )[0].files[0];

        formData.append( 'templatePath', files);


        $.ajax({
            url: FileUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            timeout: request_timeout,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data:formData,
            beforeSend: function(xhr ){

            },
            success: function(data) {
                try{

                    if(data.status =='ok'){

                    }else{

                    }
                }catch(ex){

                }



            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {


            }
        });


        return false;
    }catch(ex){

    }
}
```

**Controller function:**

```
public function upload_file(){
    try{
        $this->autoRender = false;


    } catch (Exception $e){
        return $this->EncodeError($e);
    }
}
```

The jquery seems to be fine.  Break points are hit and I can see that the object "files" is created and has the file attributes.  The controller function also gets called but the form data does not show up in my debugger (nothing in "this" or _FILES[] or any other variable).  Can anyone help out?

thanks
jason

Comment: Is your element called within an existing form, i.e. have you nested forms by any chance?

Comment: Yes.  I am trying to create a reusable element, so it can (and is) be in a nested form.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you are nesting the File upload element within another form. From nesting is not valid HTML and will confuse browsers besides not giving you the expected result. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626507/temporarily-switch-off-all-validation-on-cakephp-form-to-submit-ajax-request/21630094#21630094).

The only solution is to remove the file upload form from within your original outer form and place it outside. Use CSS to make the upload form appear within your original form.